# Xamarin.Forms How to support internationalization for TargetNullValue

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, internationalization

How can i support internationalization for TargetNullValues

in our app we have implemented internationalization with an extension which returns a bindable so that a language switch is automatically reflected in the app  without restarting the app;

```
...
TranslateExtension ...
...
    public BindingBase ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var binding = new Binding
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Path = $"[{Text}]",
            Source = LocalizationResourceManager.Instance,
        };
        return binding;
    } ...
```

this is functional in my XAML for fields where i know the text to be translated in advance;

```
...
Name="{helpers:Translate TranslateName}" />
...
```

for fields which are dynamically bound i have problems with null-values; i can give a null-value via TargetNullValue a translated text:

```
...
TargetName="{Binding SomeBinding, TargetNullValue={x:Static resources:AppResources.TranslateThisConcreteName}}"
...
```

but doing this way means that on a change of the language i have to restart the app only for the  TargetNullValue;

=> Question: is there a way to implement a TargetNullValue also bindable, dynamic or somewho, so that i do not need to restart the app?

Comment: It's not possible to set the `TargetNullValue` property with a binding expression.

Comment: yes, but how can i do a targetnullvalue dynmaically?

Comment: Maybe you could think about changing ResourceDictionary dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a converter**

Xaml

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <converters:TargetNullValueConverter x:Key="TargetNullValueConverter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<Label Text="{Binding MyStringData,Converter={StaticResource TargetNullValueConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Static misc:MyStaticData.AData}}" FontSize="Large"/>
```

Converter

```
public class TargetNullValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string data && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            return data;
        else
            return parameter;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```